# How can I store a SQL table in python to work with it?

Tags: python, sql-server

I am looking to work in python with a table that I have in SQL. I want to store the entire table in a matrix called 'mat' and then get the output after the python code so I can read the table with SQL again. This is how I started:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
server = 'myserver'
database = 'mydatabase'
username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypassword'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password) 

******Python code*******

mat=pd.read_sql('select * from mytable order by time' , con = cnxn)
```

How should I read the table to store it in mat and then how do I send it back to SQL?

Comment: Do you really want to store it in a matrix? Or are you talking about a DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

You have already read the data into a `DataFrame`. If you want to convert a dataframe to a matrix, do `mat.values`. If you want to write the data to a sql table, you will have to create a `cursor` and use it to insert the data.

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(''' INSERT INTO myTable (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('Wilsamson', 'Shiphrah') ''')
```

If you have multiple values, you should use the `executemany` command;

```
values = list(zip(mat['FirstName'].values.tolist(), mat['LastName'].values.tolist()))
cursor.executemany('''INSERT INTO myTable (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?, ?)''', values);
```

At the end of the `INSERT` statement, you will need to `commit` the inserts before closing your `cursor` and `connection`.

```
cursor.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

If you want to convert

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# use this to display ALL columns...useful, but definitely not required
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="duser_name",
  passwd="pswd",
  database="db_naem"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM YourTable")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(myresult)

df.to_csv('C:\\path_here\\test.csv', sep=',')
```

You can easily convert a dataframe to a matrix.

```
np.array(df.to_records().view(type=np.matrix))
```

But I'm not sure why you want to do that.  I think datframes are a lot more practical for most people's needs.